# Arduino Newline in serial monitor (Help)

Tags: c, arduino, newline

I want to develop a program that can read and receive a byte data from the serial, but my problem is when I'm testing the code below in serial monitor, I must change the serial monitor into newline format first, if any of you that can help me to input the data without change the newline format in serial monitor.

Here is the code:

```
byte alarmhour = 0;
byte alarmminute = 0;

void setAlarm() {
    Serial.print("Please enter the alarm hour in 24hr format, 0-23. - ");
    alarmhour = readByte();
    Serial.println(alarmhour);
    Serial.print("Please enter the alarm minute, 0-59. - ");
    alarmminute = readByte();
    Serial.println(alarmminute);
    Serial.println("The data has been entered.");

    EEPROM.write(addr + 2, alarmminute);
    EEPROM.write(addr + 3, alarmhour);
}

byte readByte() {
    while (!Serial.available()) delay(10);
    byte reading = 0;
    byte incomingByte = Serial.read();
    while (incomingByte != '\n') {
        if (incomingByte >= '0' && incomingByte <= '9'){
            reading = reading * 10 + (incomingByte - '0');
        }else{
            incomingByte = Serial.read();
        }
    }
    Serial.flush();
    return reading;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Formatting/indentation:(

Comment: Identation, that has default "no line ending".

Comment: `else;` is surely a typo. Can't be helping anything.

Comment: Ur right. I'm sorry, but that's not the problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also had that problem when I wantet to transfer data from VB.net on Windows to my arduino with Serial. I fixed it by sending a "Line ends here (!)"

```
void serialEvent() {
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char ch = (char) Serial.read();
    if (ch == '!') { //This is where it checks if the incomming (char / byte is the End of line
      stringComplete = true;
    }else if (ch == '0' || ch == '1') { //Im Sending 0 and 1 here to turn un / off LED's
      inputString += ch; 
    }
    if (stringComplete) {
      Serial.flush();
      Serial.println("<--" + inputString);
      inputString = "";
      stringComplete = false;
    }
  } 
}
```

I hope that helped you a bit. Feel free to use that code.